# Table annotation in jpa with portion of the table name dynamically

Tags: hibernate, jpa

in JPA annotation @Table(x+"_Name"), 
I want the x to be fed by spring config file.
Is it possible in JPA? actually all our db tables name have prefix with application name, and I want to use that prefix at dynamically configure by passing to spring bean config.

in spring config:

```
<bean id="x" class="java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg value="JOE" />
</bean>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313095/jpa-hibernate-and-custom-table-prefixes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444962/in-tablename-tablename-make-tablename-a-variable-in-jpa

Comment: Thanks @zmf for cross link to solution. is it possible to have two different prefix for same project? ie, x for bunch of tables and y prefix for another bunch of tables?

Comment: @kneethan if you're using hibernate(my previous link assumes that you are), once you implement a custom NamingStrategy I'd imagine you can do any sort of prefixing that you'd like. Whether or not that's a good idea is up for debate.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, You can't. Any value you will set as `@Table` annotation parameter you will receive

"The value for annotation attribute Table.name must be a constant expression" error